# Group similar strings and change their values to something common while retaining the individual rows

Tags: r, string, receipt

I have receipt data and there are descriptions of items but some are pretty similar and I'd like to code those similar ones with he same value to increase the chances of finding associations in the data. For example:

```
Strawberries
Premium Strawberries
Premium Strawberries 
Hass Avocado
Mini Avocado
```

I'd like to have:

```
Strawberries
Strawberries
Strawberries
Avocado
Avocado
```

Something to that effect but I'm open to suggestions for sure.All I can think of is that some sort of fuzzy search might be what I need I just don't know how to implement that?

Thanks, once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way are string distances. But be careful because they do not capture any meaning, just the similarity between actual strings. Below example could work like some heuristic, but pay attention to last example. Higher the threshold in cutree, less groups you will have, and probably more wrongly classified examples. Ergo lower threshold means that you are more strict, and possibly missing good solutions:

```
th <- 0.35 ## between 0 and 1
roles <- c("Strawberies","strawberries","Mini strawberries","Avocado","Hass avocado","Not Avocado")
mat <- stringdist::stringdistmatrix(roles,roles,method = "jw",p=0.025,nthread = parallel::detectCores())
colnames(mat) <- roles
rownames(mat) <- roles
t <- hclust(as.dist(mat),method = "single")
memb <- cutree(t,h=th) 
df <- data.frame(a=c(roles),b=c(memb),stringsAsFactors = F)
df$to <- plyr::mapvalues(df$b,from=1:length(unique(memb)),to=df$a[!duplicated(df$b)])

prior <- data.frame(str=roles,to=df$to,stringsAsFactors = F)
prior
                str          to
1       Strawberies Strawberies
2      strawberries Strawberies
3 Mini strawberries Strawberies
4           Avocado     Avocado
5      Hass avocado     Avocado
6       Not Avocado     Avocado
```

Comment: I did this and it’s exactly what I wanted just one thing , it turned everything to strawberries haha what could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: It would turn to the first match it got, so if strawberries and strawberies haha will got grouped to the same thing, and strawberries haha would appear first in roles above, then it would get matched to straw. haha... just change the order of appearance, i usually order by frequence of appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you receipt is a dataframe `df`, i.e.,

```
df <- data.frame("Strawberries",
"Premium Strawberries",
"Premium Strawberries",
"Hass Avocado",
"Mini Avocado",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

then maybe you can achieve it via

```
res <- gsub(".*\\s(\\w)","\\1",df$name)
```

yielding

```
>res
[1] "Strawberries" "Strawberries" "Strawberries" "Avocado"     
[5] "Avocado"
```